# Using multiple datasources in report : no suitable driver found

Tags: jdbc, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using *iReport 5.7*.
I have a report using  XML datasource and a for the subreport , i need to have a database connection. 
I have added a parameter with the default expression:

```
  java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.8.77:1521:MYDB","user","MYPASS" )
```

But I got an error message saying that there is no suitable driver found .

I found somewhere that i need to add the expression :

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

I can't figure out where to add it

Answer (score 0):

You can download jar file to connect to 10g database, you need to download `classes.12.jar` file from: [Oracle 10g JDBC Drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc101040-094982.html)

To add JDBC driver, go to: `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Class Path` -> `Add jar file`.

Now you should be able to connect database using following steps:

1. Click on Database icon -> `New` -> `JDBC Connection` -> `Next`.
2. JDBC Driver class - Oracle (`oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`)
3. URL Syntax : `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:DatabaseName`

   Example 1: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl` (where `orcl` is SID of your Oracle database)

   Example 2: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.9:1521:orcl` (Remote database connection using IP)
4. Username & Password
5. Click on `Test Connection...`. If the connection is successful click on `OK` button.

Comment: I already added the jdbc driver to the classpath of the project . The  steps you just described are for main reports , I can't find how to connect the database to my " subreport" !

Answer (score 0):

1. In your main report, create un parameter (ex: DRIVER_CLASS)
2. Then give it type `java.lang.Class`
3. Finaly, in its expression default value put your

   ```
   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
   ```

Build and run your report.